# Stored procedure being called multiple times when it should be called only once

Tags: sql, sql-server, mybatis

I'm working in Java using MyBatis to call a stored procedure in SQL Server. This sproc takes one parameter. In my code, right before I call the sproc, I check that these param is not null, and I log its value.

This works fine and as expected on my test environment. When I tried production, though, I noticed the logs were showing

```
1 - [INFO] Calling PR_ProcedureName with ParameOneName=validNonNullValue
2 - [ERROR] Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Procedure or function 'PR_ProcedureName' expects parameter '@@ParamOneName', which was not supplied.
3 - [ERROR] Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Procedure or function 'PR_ProcedureName' expects parameter '@@ParamOneName', which was not supplied.
```

When I look in the DB, I can see the sproc updated the appropriate values. So it seems like it ran successfully once, then was triggered again two times without any supplied parameters.

I suspect that the subsequent faulty calls to the proc are not being triggered by any code I wrote, but maybe by the MyBatis mapper. It's not being triggered at the DB level either, since the application is getting exceptions.

The way my app is written, the sproc would never be called without passing a valid parameter.

Relevant mapper method in Java:

```
void callProcedure(@Param("ParamOne") UUID paramOne)
```

And the corresponding XML:

```
<update id="callProcedure" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="Uuid">
{
    CALL dbo.PR_ProcedureName (
        @ParamOne = #{paramOne},
    )
}
</update>
```

Comment: We would need more information to help.  Try to set a breakpoint in the code where it is called.  Then you can step through the first time, and then see why it is called a second and third time.

Comment: I would run a `SQL search` on your `database` and check to see everywhere that `stored procedure` is run. If it is being used as a `service`, then the properties window should show you everything going on with it. Screen shot all the info on that window, and we may be able to figure it out.

Comment: Since it fails, what is the next step? I mean "When Fail - Restart" try 2x?

Comment: First, you need to post the mapper, so we can help you. Second, if this works well in TEST but not in PROD, it seems to me the stored procedures are different between those two environments. Are you sure you deployed the latest stored procedure version to PROD?

Comment: I edited the question a bit. After more debugging I've concluded that it must be something in MyBatis that's calling the sproc two additional times, without any params.

My code checks for valid params and logs a statement before calling `mapper.callProcedure(paramOne)`. I'm only seeing that statement once in the logs. After that, the two errors are being thrown.

I've verified the sprocs are the same on both envs. Is there any function of MyBatis that repeats calls or something like that? I've not much experience with it.